# C# Visual Studio tab control add more pages to a tab

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs, controls, tabcontrol

Im have a simple question about the TabControl in C#-
I want to have more than one page connected to each tab.
So that if I change between the tab, the contents of two pages will change.
Like in this example: http://i49.tinypic.com/260zino.jpg
Both pages should be connected to a tab.

Is it possible to do this?
If so, how?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So a tab control with a fly-out?

Comment: You could add 2 separate custom controls.

Comment: Both pages should be visible at all times, only the information on the pages should change when the tabs are switched, ScruffyDuck.
How do I do that, Antarr Byrd?

Answer (score 0):

Would a bigger tab control containing two panels not do what you need?

Comment: I need to do exactly as the example in the picture looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the tab as a container for two smaller containers side by side, each being a 'page'.

You could use a GroupBox control for each page to visually separate the two.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but how do I accomplish that? 
I'll try it out and we will see if i succeed with a little googling.
Thanks!

Comment: Try setting the dock property to left for one and right for the other to get the groupboxes where you want them.  You can also look at a [split panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) control to do the sizing for you and then just dock the group boxes.